# Plot rectangle using coordinates in Excel

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-excel, vba, macros, charts

I want to plot a Rectangle using Excel charts with help of only 2 coordinates, bottom left and top right.
Is there a way I can define use the Microsoft Office 365 Pro plus Excel version.

[image]

---

For example:

```
Element_name   X_low    Y_low   X_high  Y_high
CM124_BK124    4       4        16      64
CM124_BK8      4       4        16      64
```

Here is my attempt using `treemap` from Excel Chart options; It's not much of help.
[image]

Comment: What have you researched and attempted so far?

Comment: I tried to use `treemap`  but that chart is not suitable for coordinates.

Comment: You'll need to have all the four coordinates. You might do it with scatter plot.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you can do it in native Excel but if you are willing to use an add-in it is possible. Funfun add-in allows you to create this kind of chart by using Javascript in Excel.

Here is a working code I have written for you:

https://www.funfun.io/1/#/edit/5a69ddc9ee0b8c3283c653e0

I used the format you wanted, I just changed the data to create two different rectangles, both having only two coordinates.

As you can see in this link, I used an online editor from Funfun where I entered your table in the embedded spreadsheet.

I use a JSON file to get the data from the spreadsheet to my javascript code as such:

```
{
    "data": "=A1:E3"
}
```

I then store the data in local variables and create my rectangles with the correct coordinates, as such:

```
/* we store the data from the spreadsheet in local variables */
var label = [];
var x = [];
var y = [];

for (var i = 1; i < $internal.data.length; i++)
{
  label.push($internal.data[i][0]);
  x.push([parseInt($internal.data[i][1]), parseInt($internal.data[i][3])]);
  y.push([parseInt($internal.data[i][2]), parseInt($internal.data[i][4])]);  
}

/* create all the shapes you want with the data stored */
var shapes = [];
var traces = [];
for (var i = 0; i < $internal.data.length - 1; i++) {
  shapes.push({
    type: 'rectangle',
      xref: 'x',
      yref: 'y',
      fillcolor: 'rgba(50, 171, 96, 0.7)',
      x0: x[i][0],
      y0: y[i][0],
      x1: x[i][1],
      y1: y[i][1],
      line: {
        color: 'rgba(50, 171, 96, 1)'
      }
  });
  traces.push({
    x: [x[i][0] + 3.5],
    y: [y[i][0] - 2],
    text: label[i],
    mode: 'text'
  });
}
```

the `shapes` array is for the rectangles and the `trace` is to label each rectangle.

You can customize your chart as you like there are a lot of options available, that is the beauty of javascript and its powerful libraries. For this example I used [plotly.js](https://plot.ly/javascript/)

You can load it in Excel by pasting the URL in the [Funfun Excel add-in](https://www.funfun.io/1/msaddin). Here is how it looks like with my example:

[image: final]

**Edit**

If you want to write text inside the shapes you just need another local variables with the values stored in it and find the correct coordinates as such:

```
var textInRectangles = ["First", "second"];

...

 traces.push({
    x: [x[i][0] + 2.5],
    y: [y[i][0] + 4],
    text: textInRectangles[i],
    textfont: {
    color: 'black',
    size: 9,
    family: 'Arial'
  },
    mode: 'text'
  });
```

[image: edit]

I changed the link of the example up ahead.

**Disclosure : I’m a developer of Funfun.**

Comment: This looks excellent, But I also need to write certain values within those boxes created.

Comment: I edited my answer, explaining how to write inside the rectangles. I hope it answers your question, if not don't hesitate to comment again :)

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with a scatter plot, but you need to enter all corners' coordinates:

[image]

Comment: But I want to plot multiple entries with help of only 2 co-ordinates.

Comment: I understand you want it, then Excel might not be the right tool for you.